# Enclose polygons that are not overlapped and remove gaps between them?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, polygon

I have to create a big polygon with the outer ring from some selected polygons that are close to each other like in the picture.

[image: Polygon1]

Is it somehow possible two fill the small gap between the polygons as shown in the other picture

[image: Polygon2]

I'm using this query:

```sql
 SELECT ST_ExteriorRing((ST_DUMP(ST_Union(the_geom))).geom) FROM parcel
```

to get the outer line but get 4 rows result.

What do I've to do to get only one row of the outer line without the gaps?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/316124/120129

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the [PostGIS Addons](https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons/blob/master/postgis_addons.sql) and do something like:

```
SELECT ST_BufferedUnion(ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(ST_Union(the_geom))).geom), 10) geom
FROM parcel
```

ST_BufferedUnion() will make a buffer around your polygons, union them into a single polygon and then remove the buffer. 10 is the size of the buffer. It should be a bit more than the half of width of the gap you want to remove.